# Activate Environment Within Jupyter Notebook Using Shell Commands

Tags: python, shell, jupyter-notebook, ipython

I installed an environment using **venv** named `probe-detection`. In the terminal, I am able to activate/deactivate as usual.

```
C:\Users\212765830>C:/Users/212765830/probe-detection/scripts/activate

(probe-detection) C:\Users\212765830>echo %VIRTUAL_ENV%
C:\Users\212765830\probe-detection

(probe-detection) C:\Users\212765830>deactivate
C:\Users\212765830>echo %VIRTUAL_ENV%
%VIRTUAL_ENV%
```

Within this environment, I installed some libraries I needed for a python script. I want to run this python script within a Jupyter notebook. But, I am unable to activate the environment with the IPython commands.

```
In: [1]
!C:/Users/212765830/probe-detection/scripts/activate
!echo %VIRTUAL_ENV%

Out: [1]
%VIRTUAL_ENV%
```

The output of `!echo %VIRTUAL_ENV%` being `%VIRTUAL_ENV%` shows that the environment activation hasn't been successful. Is there a way to activate an environment within the IPython shell?

Thanks!

OS: Windows